# After installing python3.7, virtualenv and pip on newly installed 20.04, terminal window will not open

Tags: command-line, python, 20.04, xfce, paths

I needed to install python3.7, virtualenv, and pip. After doing so, I added `~/.local/bin` to $PATH. I echo'd $PATH and saw that it added `.local/bin` and then closed the terminal app. Terminal will no longer open. When I try to open it, I just get a spinning wheel. I can open Xfce terminal. When I check PATH in Xfce, I no longer see `~/.local/bin`. Also, after I updated the PATH, I can no longer open Jupyter Notebook using python3. I get an error,

> Creating Notebook Failed
> An error occurred while creating a new notebook.
> Permission denied: .ipynb_checkpoints

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Um... what happens if you remove your mod to PATH?

Comment: When I echo $PATH from Xfce terminal, I don't see the modified path, but still can't open Jupyter Notebook (python3) or default terminal app.

Xfce terminal:
PATH = /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: Tell me WHAT FILE you edited PATH, and show me the PATH line that you edited.

Comment: I'm copying the following line from ~/.bash_history. In old terminal window, I typed the following:

export PATH="/home/craig/.local/bin:$PATH"

Afterwards, I typed echo $PATH and saw that it was added to the path. Now, when I type echo $PATH, I see: export PATH="/home/craig/.local/bin:$PATH"

Comment: So you **didn't** actually edit any .profile or .bash* files?... you just typed your commands interactively in the terminal window? If so, log out, log in, and see if terminal now starts. If it still doesn't, reboot, retry terminal.

Comment: I think you're right. I logged out/in and terminal now works. Jupyter Notebook still doesn't work. It opens, but when I try to create new python3 I get the same error above. Here's the PATH: craig@craig-MS-7A38:~$ echo $PATH
/home/craig/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: I can open an existing ipynb, and it looks like it is using python3.7 (typed help() and it returned "Welcome to Python 3.7's help utility!"

Comment: Ultimately I want to install turi create, which apparently doesn't work on python 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that a `~/.local/bin` folder exists.

Edit `~/.profile` and add this to the end of the file...

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private .local/bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Log out.

Log in.

`echo $PATH`

Comment: Yes, I think this is the correct answer. Now I have to figure out how to make Jupyter Notebook work. I guess I can't accept the answer based on my reputation <15

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.8 is the default version in 20.04 and is the base for many applications. If you absolutely need 3.7 then install it also (preferably locally) but don't downgrade to 3.7.

Comment: I kept python 3.8 and installed 3.7, but after the install exporting PATH, I'm no longer able to use Jupyter Notebook or terminal.